# C++ check whether a classes object contains a certain element

Tags: c++, class, vector

Lets say i Have a class like this

```
class Person 
{
private:
  int id;
  string name ,lastname;
  vector<Person> likedperson;
public:
//getter setters
}
```

how to check likedperson  has a certain id like

```
Person user;
if(user.likedperson.contains(34))
    //do stuff
else 
    //do stuff
```

Comment: i took all of the likedperson with getter then check every element with if statement

Comment: And? Did it work? Show your code, tell us what problems you encountered. Explain why what you have isn't sufficient, and what you're looking for in any answer.

Comment: ofc it worked but its a long code and its hard to do that 50 times ı was just looking for a simple method like that

Comment: You mean like the `std::find` algorithm?

Comment: Please post code that actually compiles. Class `Person` cannot have a member of type `vector<Person>`.

Comment: actually  i have a class person and it contains person vector and it works didnt get any errors related to that

Comment: @PeteBecker the C++ Standard makes it undefined behaviour (no diagnostic required) ; some implementations do not give any errors or warnings and work as intended

Comment: @asdasdasd you should use a different data structure even if this compiles for you. Aside from not being well-defined, this structure makes it impossible to represent any loops (e.g. A likes B, and B also likes A).  Instead you will need to list the liked-people by reference .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `std::find_if` that uses a UnaryPredicate, something like:

```
if (std::find_if(std::begin(likedperson), std::end(likedperson), 
    [](const Person& p) -> bool { return p.id == 34; }) != std::end(likedperson)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike some languages, C++ mostly separates the algorithms that operate on containers (things that store data) from the containers themselves.

There's a standard algorithm to find an element, if it exists, in any container: `std::find`. (See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find for more details.)

You want something like

```
if (std::find(likedperson.begin(), likedperson.end(), 34) != likedperson.end())
```

Comment: should i use like this ?if(std::find(user[0].likedperson.begin(),user[0].likedperson.end(),32 ) !=user[0].likedperson.end())

Comment: Yes, if `user` is an array or vector. Although you might want to write this as a member function of `Person`, rather than outside the class, so that you could then call it like `if (user[0].likes(32))`.